# Android: Client not ready yet..Waiting for process to come online

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I am getting the error below; whenever I try to launch the app it crashes.
I have tried a few times using an emulator and also using my mobile, but it still doesn't work.

I'm using Firebase auth and database in the project. Although there are no errors, I wonder if it has any affect on the error?

```
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.juice.health/com.example.juice.health.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet..Waiting for process to come online
Connected to process 3016 on device Nexus_5X_API_23 [emulator-5554]
Application terminated.
```

Manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.juice.health">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".ProfileActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".EditProfileActivity"></activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Have you tried to restart your emulator? Also could you post AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: @HonorLT yes , i tried few times , and also with my phone , its the same , manifest posted. thanks

Comment: try to remove this line inside intent-filter: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />   
as I see, you have declared it above so there is no need to repeat it.

Comment: @HonorLT already removed, still the same.

Comment: Try for android studio: select Run--->Attach debugger to android process. Or if you application isn't a Top secret, you can send me the project and I can test it on my environment.

Comment: @HonorLT its not working too , sure thanks !! how can i send it to you

Comment: you can uppload it somewhere on the Internet (probably Dropbox or Google Drive are the best options) and then give me the link. I will download it and see if it's working.

Comment: @HonorLT https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_NcY2raMYjjV25rWUR1UlB2RXc there you go ! thanks

Comment: I imported the application and ran it on emulator. The same problem occured. I am trying to figure out how to solve it and I will get in touch with you as soon as possible.

Comment: @HonorLT Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: I have the same problem now, but with a class of QR code scan

Answer (score 9):

In Android-Studio : File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart

Try it

Answer (score 2):

follow this steps

1. go to the phone setting
2. "select developer option"
3. "select app to be debugged"

and select your application,

and ready

[image]

Comment: What if this is on an emulator?

Answer (score 0):

My similar error had to do with material design and colors somehow interfering. Changed the parent theme for style away from Material but kept noactionbar and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

**This solution only works on Android Studio versions *earlier than 3.2.x*.**

Follow these steps:

1. Clean your project
2. Go to **Tools**>**Android** and **Enable ADB Integration**

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when i migrated to androidx. I changed `styles.xml` App theme for one of the Material one. You can check the full list [here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#4-change-your-app-theme-to-inherit-from-a-material-components-theme):

Answer (score 0):

Disable "Instant Run" in Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Instant Run as [Honor LT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5551988/honor-lt) suggested in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43327033/android-client-not-ready-yet-waiting-for-process-to-come-online#comment73721609_43328227).

Answer (score 0):

In my case the minSDK in the AndroidManifest.xml file doesn't match to SDK that I have installed.
Try to use latest SDK that you have in your machine.

android:minSdkVersion="[your_latest_SDK]"

or install SDK that match that required by the app.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is targeting API level 28 (Android 9.0) or above, you must include the following declaration within the  element of Android Manifest.

```
 <uses-library
  android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
  android:required="false" />
```

If your app is targeting a lower API level, this is handled for you.

my case was adding a Google map into my App with an Intent

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all dependencies added for your project.
It also through same

Client not ready yet..Waiting for process to come online
Connected to process 3016 on device Nexus_5X_API_23 [emulator-5554]
Application terminated.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was an asset file missing. I just took a file to photoshop to edit and forgot to put it back.

Answer (score -1):

Well, after editing manifest a bit I do not receive this error anymore:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.juice.health">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:fullBackupContent="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".ProfileActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".EditProfileActivity"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

[image]

Comment: maybe try to disable instant run? File → Settings → Build, Execution, Deployment → Instant Run and uncheck Enable Instant Run.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem.No matter whether I ran it using debug mode or normal mode, I still had the same problem. I solved the issue by disabling 'INSTANT MODE'. It worked for me

Comment: How to disable "INSTANT MODE"? Please answer that part.

Comment: I still haв the trouble after disabling 'INSTANT MODE'.

Answer (score -1):

Sync the project,
If you are using Kotlin, you may have to configure it.
Syc project shall help to configure.