# Client not ready yet..Waiting for process to come online updated version of Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

My android studio project is failing to run and the run says "Client not ready yet..". I have viewed another answer to this issue [Android: Client not ready yet..Waiting for process to come online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43327033/android-client-not-ready-yet-waiting-for-process-to-come-online/43418069?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) but android studio has since updated and I can no longer see the android tab on Tools.

Below I've attached the screen shot of my tools tab and the error that i'm receiving.

This question is not a repeat as the layout of android studio has changed since the previous questions and I am unable to find the android tab

[image: Tools bar]

[image: App wont run]

Comment: What is the solution?  I have the same problem...

Comment: I have the same issue and I dont knw how to solve it!

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to get a **java.lang.RuntimeException:** Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo exception and that is the activity that you are trying to start is **abstract**. I made this stupid mistake once and it's very easy to overlook.